# Array não passa completo pelo json

Tags: php, json

Boa noite,
estou tentando passar um array para o json mas ele só passa a última variavel

```
function GetSuppliersView() {
    global $db;
    global $id;
    global $type;
    try{
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM suppliers WHERE id = $id");
        $row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $result['success'] = true;
        $result['result'] = $row;
        $querytwo = $db->query("SELECT name FROM third_party_services LEFT JOIN suppliers_services ON third_party_services.id = suppliers_services.id WHERE supplier_id=$id");
        $x=0;
        while($services = $querytwo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
             $var[$x] = $services['name'];
        }
        $result['secondresult'] = array_values($var);
        echo json_encode($result);
    return true;
    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

A variável **$result['result']** passa certo, porém a **$result['secondresult']** só passa o último item a ser atribuido

Comment: Testa usar `$row=$query->fetch_assoc(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` assim tens uma array que podes exportar com `json_encode` e `echo`.

Comment: O `$x` é sempre `0`, não incrementa, é esperado que somente fique o último.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o seu código:

```
$x = 0; // <<<

while($services = $querytwo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $var[$x] = $services['name'];
}
```

O `$x` sempre será `0`, você tem várias opções para corrigir isso:

```
$x = 0;

while($services = $querytwo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $var[$x] = $services['name'];
      $x++; // <<<
}
```

Isso irá sempre incrementar o valor anterior (se for *int*  será 0, 1, 2, 3...). Se você quiser utilize `$x = $x + 1` como uma outra alternativa,  <sub><sub>o `$x++` pode ter alguns efeitos "inesperados" em alguns casos, não neste.</sub></sub>

Entretanto se ele parte de `0`, pode simplesmente utilizar:

```
while($services = $querytwo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $var[] = $services['name'];
}
```

---

O MySQLi possui o `mysqli_fetch_all()`. O PDO parece ter o equivalente `fetchAll()`, segundo a documentação. Ele parece pegar todos os resultados, então experimente também ver o `fetchAll()`.

Supostamente isto deve funcionar também:

```
$querytwo = $db->query("SELECT name FROM third_party_services LEFT JOIN suppliers_services ON third_party_services.id = suppliers_services.id WHERE supplier_id=$id");

$result['secondresult'] = $querytwo->fetchAll();

echo json_encode($result);
```

*Mas, não estou totalmente certo disso. ;)*